# How to re run suite without using listener in testng

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, testng

I had a requirement to re-run a complete suite from the TestNG test method itself if any of the test-case from the suite failed. Is there any way to call complete suite using an `XML` file or Test class within the Test method? The complete suite should re-run the after-class method or teardown test-case or last test-case

`@AfterClass` or `@AfterMethod` I can't use due to some other functionality I'm handling into it. I require to check in the last test method if any of the above test methods got failed then I should rerun the complete suite or class.

Or please suggest if there is any listener that tracks which test failed, suppose I had some 10 tests methods in which 3 and 7 are the main tests if they failed I had to rerun the complete suite that should check at the end of the test method (In Test method 10 we can say as per example.)

Comment: any specific reason why you don't want to use a listener?

Comment: Hi @GauthamM, I had a requirement to run a complete suite from the TestNG test method itself. Is there any way to call complete suite using an XML file or Test class within the Test method?

Comment: Also, by _..within the test method.._ do you mean that you cannot use `AfterSuite`? It would be good if you could elaborate the question with such details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use rerun the suite in an `AfterSuite` method.

In your test class which would hold the `AfterSuite` method, declare two static `int` variables to keep the number of reruns and maximum allowed rerun count.
Then in the `AfterSuite` method check this count and rerun the suite if maximum is not reached.

```java
public class AnyTestClass {
    private static int counter;
    private static final int MAX_RERUN = 4;
    
    // replace "" with location of your suite xml -> something like src/test/......
    private static final String SUITE_LOC = "";

    // test methods.....

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite(ITestContext ctx) {
        if(counter == MAX_RERUN) {
            return;
        }
      
        if(ctx.getFailedTests().size() > 0) {            
            counter++;

            // you could also have this list as static final in the class.
            List<String> suiteFiles = new ArrayList<>();
            suiteFiles.add(SUITE_LOC);
    
            TestNG runner = new TestNG();
            runner.setTestSuites(suiteFiles);
            runner.run();
        }
    }
}
```